# IDLE выдаёт ошибку в синтаксисе, не могу найти

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можете ,пожалуйста, объяснить новичку че здесь не так?

```
age = int(input("Сколько вам лет?"))
name = str(input("Вас зовут Вася?"))
if name=="да" or name =="Да" or name =="ДА":
    print("Привет, Вася, тебе str(age) лет")
else:
     namee = str(input("Тогда как вас зовут?")
     print("Привет, str(namee) , тебе str(age) лет")
```

Comment: Одна скобка не закрыта на предпоследней строке

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая ошибка:

```
namee = str(input("Тогда как вас зовут?")
```

здесь в конце не хватает закрытие скоби. В конце добавьте `)`

Вторая ошибка:

```
print("Привет, Вася, тебе str(age) лет")
```

и

```
print("Привет, str(namee) , тебе str(age) лет")
```

надо сделать так:

```
print("Привет, Вася, тебе " + str(age) + "лет")
```

и

```
print("Привет" + namee + ", тебе" + str(age) + " лет")
```

также советую почитать про [форматирование строк](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html) и [F - строки](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings)

И третье `input` возвращает строку по этому `str(input())` писать ни надо.

---

И вот это:

```
if name=="да" or name =="Да" or name =="ДА":
```

можно заменить на это:

```
if name.lower() == "да":
```

Функция `lower()` возвращает копию строки, в которой все символы в нижнем регистре.

Comment: Поскольку питон 3-й, то может вообще f-строки использовать, а не конкатенировать строки вручную, это не очень красиво

Comment: Спасибо всем большое! Третий день изучаю, лол